# Symfony 3.4 and it's documentation

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

Symfony 3.4 download section is instructing me to install the skeleton application using composer command. But the documentation page is asking me to follow a different set of instructions to get Symfony using the command `symfony new`.

Also, if I install Symfony 3.4 skeleton using the Composer command, then I'm not able to follow the documentation for 3.4. Instead, the documentation for 4.0 is working well with this Symfony 3.4 (installed via composer).

If I install Symfony 3.4 using Composer command, then the directory structure is different when compared to a Symfony 3.4 installed via `symfony new` command.

I understand that Symfony Flex is introduced and that is why only the skeleton is being installed initially. Is there any specific documentation section available that gives instructions on how to proceed further (after installing Symfony skeleton using Composer)?

Comment: @Joe's answer covers the question.  Just wanted to point out that (symfony/website-skeleton)[https://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-the-symfony-standard-edition] is now available which gives you most of the features that the standard package used to.  If you are planning on staying with 3.4 for the next few years then follow it's documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This topic is currently also being discussed on the symfony repo because of the inconsistency you encountered:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25727

I'd say if you do want to use the Flex structure with 3.4 you could just stick to the symfony 4.0 docs since 4.0 is feature identical to 3.4.